# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined Morris.js

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, bootstrap-datepicker, morris.js

I have a bar chart and a date picker Bootstrap
My bar chart works perfectly, it loads the data when selecting a day. 
But in developer tool i'm having these annoying errors:

Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined Morris 1590
Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Morris 424

I would like to know how to solve this. I don't want to have those errors there.

```
     function hourString(hour) {
     if (hour === 0) {
         return "12:00 am";
     }
     if (hour < 12) {
         return hour + ":00 am";
     }
     if (hour === 12) {
         return "12:00 pm";
     }
     return (hour - 12) + ":00 pm";
 }

  var ordersPackChart =
     Morris.Bar({
         element: 'morris-bar-chart',
         data: [],
         xkey: 'y',
         ykeys: ['a'],
         ymax: 1000,
         labels: ['Pack per hour'],
         hideHover: true,
         resize: true,
         barColors: ['#ed5565'],
         parseTime: false
     });

 function packResult(historydate, result) {
     result = JSON.parse(result);

     var data = [];
     for (var hour = 6; hour < 24; hour++) {

         var numberPack = 0;
         for (var i = 0; i < result.Result.length; i++) {
             if (result.Result[i].PACK_HOUR == hour) {
                 numberPack = result.Result[i].NUM_ORDER_PACK;
                 break;
             }
         }

         data.push({ y: hourString(hour), a: numberPack });
     }

     ordersPackChart.setData(data);
 }


 $(document).ready(function () {        
     $("#fromdate").datepicker({
         autoclose: true
     }).change(dateChanged)
       .on('changeDate', dateChanged);
      });

 function dateChanged(ev) {
     $(this).datepicker('hide');

     var day = $('#fromdate').val();

     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: '@Url.Action("GetQueryResult")',
         context: document.body,
         data: {
             querySetName: 'dashboard-packorder-statistics',
             queryName: 'OrderPack',
             historydate: day
         },
         success: function (result) {
             packResult(ordersPackChart.HISTORY_DATE, result);
         },
         error: function (xhr) {
             var message = "ErrorStatus: " + xhr.status + "  ReadyState: " + xhr.readyState;
         }
     });
 }

 // Reload the Morris chart
 jQuery(function ($) {
     $('#fromdate').on('change', function () {
         ordersPackChart.options.fromdate = $(this).is('changeDate');
         ordersPackChart.redraw();
     });
 });
```

Comment: Does the stacktrace say what line of your code triggered the error? Some where in it (if the trace isnt too large) it should reference a line to one of your js files.

Comment: Yes. IN line 1590

Comment: It just reference to Morris.js line 1590. And the other error in morris.js in line 424.

Comment: No, thats the libray, if you click the arrow next to the error message it will expand the stacktrace, and have lines like `at something (somefile.js:71)` one of those should reference one of your own js files. If it doesn't you might have to cut away some of the code one part at a time till you find which part is actually the root cause.

Comment: When I click it it sends me to the library of Morris.js, or maybe I don't understand what you mean. This is the hole message of the error:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined
    at Bar.Morris.Bar.Bar.hoverContentForRow (morris.js:1590)
    at Bar.Morris.Bar.Bar.onHoverMove (morris.js:1578)
    at morris.js:11
    at Bar.Morris.EventEmitter.EventEmitter.fire (morris.js:42)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (morris.js:116)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)

Comment: have you made sure the data you are sending to `setData()` is proper? Try `console.log(data)` before the call to make sure it is

Comment: umm I did and it says Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: I also deleted that part in my code that says Reload the morris chart. I deleted cause it was causing one of the errors at the end. right now I'm just having the one that says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined

Comment: You probably put the log in the wrong place, meant for it to go above `ordersPackChart.setData(data);`

Comment: My bad, I put it in a wrong place. Now I did it right. And in console I get this with the errors:   
DPackingOrderStatistics:488 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Answer (score 2):

I fix my problem. 
Every time my mouse was hovering in the chart with no data was giving those errors. SO I fixed that. And also I was calling the event of the datepicker twice.

These are my changes

```
       function hourString(hour) {
     if (hour === 0) {
         return "12:00 am";
     }
     if (hour < 12) {
         return hour + ":00 am";
     }
     if (hour === 12) {
         return "12:00 pm";
     }
     return (hour - 12) + ":00 pm";
 }

  var ordersPackChart;

 function packResult(historydate, result) {
     result = JSON.parse(result);

     var data = [];
     for (var hour = 6; hour < 24; hour++) {

         var numberPack = 0;
         for (var i = 0; i < result.Result.length; i++) {
             if (result.Result[i].PACK_HOUR == hour) {
                 numberPack = result.Result[i].NUM_ORDER_PACK;
                 break;
             }
         }

         data.push({ y: hourString(hour), a: numberPack });
     }

     if (ordersPackChart != null) {
         ordersPackChart.setData(data);
     } else {
         ordersPackChart =
             Morris.Bar({
                 element: 'morris-bar-chart',
                 data: data,
                 xkey: 'y',
                 ykeys: ['a'],
                 ymax: 1000,
                 labels: ['Pack per hour'],
                 hideHover: true,
                 resize: true,
                 barColors: ['#ed5565'],
                 parseTime: false
             });
     }
 }


 $(document).ready(function () {        
     $("#fromdate").datepicker({
         autoclose: true
     }).change(dateChanged);
 });

 var currentDay;

 function dateChanged(ev) {
     $(this).datepicker('hide');

     var day = $('#fromdate').val();
     if (day == currentDay)
         return;

     currentDay = day;

     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: '@Url.Action("GetQueryResult")',
         context: document.body,
         data: {
             querySetName: 'dashboard-packorder-statistics',
             queryName: 'OrderPack',
             historydate: day
         },
         success: function (result) {
             packResult(day, result);
         },
         error: function (xhr) {
             var message = "ErrorStatus: " + xhr.status + "  ReadyState: " + xhr.readyState;
         }
     });
 }
```